# Hiding buttons using a leveling mechanic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an idle/incremental game and need some help with my leveling mechanics.  I have everything working but I needed pointed in the right direction.  I'm trying to hide some upgrade buttons for the game behind a certain level i.e. once I hit level 5 I can get the next upgrade but I want to be able to show the first upgrade right away.  Is there a way to do this without using canvas groups?

Edit: Here is the code I used on how to do that particular thing.

```
public int l2;
public int l3;
public int l4;
public GameObject Button1;
public GameObject Button2;
public GameObject Button3;
public LevelingManager levelingManager;

void Start()
{
    Button1.SetActive(false);
    Button2.SetActive(false);
    Button3.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (levelingManager.curLevel >= l2)
    {
        Button1.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Button1.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (levelingManager.curLevel >= l3)
    {
        Button2.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Button2.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (levelingManager.curLevel >= l4)
    {
        Button3.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Button3.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: `.enabled = false`?

Comment: I was able to do everything by using the .SetActive(True/False).  Thanks Draco18s, the .enabled led me right to it!